# ActionBar calendar spinner

Tags: android, calendar, widget, spinner

In the [android design guidance](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/design/building-blocks/spinners.html) there is an image of "ActionBar calendar spinner":

[image]

Is there a code realization for this widget (if exists)? Is it a native SDK widget or just design pattern?

Comment: I would love to know how they do that too..

Comment: Did you get any good link ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the native calendar app is not open source, so i doubt that you'll find the source code somewhere around the web.

But you probably can solve that by creating a custom adapter and inflating different layouts for `getView()` (current/selected item) and `getDropDownView()` (spinner rows).

**Edit:** I just saw the calendar app became open-source. Here is the git-Link: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar.git

I would be curious too whether the extended ActionBar list navigation is a pattern or a custom widget. Would you post your results after checking out the source?

Answer (score 0):

Quite late for the OP now, but thought that i could help by-passers. 
You can achieve a similar look and functionality by modifying the code provided in this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/   .

Just read the section about the actionBar Spinner. Than modify the related methods to include two textviews (or one textview with tabbed space to achieve Day tab Dec 1) instead of icon/textview.